# PHP: Preg_match (new challenge)

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a html look like this (its javascript for flash player):

```
var flashvars =
            {
                'autoplay'          : autoplay,
                'autoreplay'        : 'false',
                'start'             : '',
                'hideLinkPane'      : 'true',
                'disable_sharebar'  : 'true',
                'disablePauseroll'  : disablePauseroll,
                'video_url'         : encodeURIComponent('WQFuk9Py2VC3jsCrPDJ69xtsj33MiXAElBzQw3TSHqOOyDYL0vRJELrB1hTTW3NG0A54kE2FVueuHMkQd8JveYb92eV+dYH4IUrrvJdP5Of9HGi+5i6GT11nL0dAv/ecyP4sB0jM8rVZzyS8imLarvPUvPuFPvvB8nwYXZ2ZKon4IPjmtC8SPftaw0PSuZKMg735hLCraeAE3lMQbRwiY7yMHKmUHDALG1Ky+HBDiK20vAGEIMwzPwKZmhbBXRGiHzEiXiRk4JgaVyp6N66EALao7VOE7UTzJLs='),
                'encrypted'         : 'true',
                'video_title'       : "some cool vids title here",
                'embed_js'          : "",
                'prerollRepeat'     : "false"
            };
```

how can i use preg_match to extract the value for video_title so that it become:

echo $videoTitle;

will output: some cool vids title here

and for video_url will output:

WQFuk9Py2VC3jsCrPDJ69xtsj33MiXAElBzQw3TSHqOOyDYL0vRJELrB1hTTW3NG0A54kE2FVueuHMkQd8JveYb92eV+dYH4IUrrvJdP5Of9HGi+5i6GT11nL0dAv/ecyP4sB0jM8rVZzyS8imLarvPUvPuFPvvB8nwYXZ2ZKon4IPjmtC8SPftaw0PSuZKMg735hLCraeAE3lMQbRwiY7yMHKmUHDALG1Ky+HBDiK20vAGEIMwzPwKZmhbBXRGiHzEiXiRk4JgaVyp6N66EALao7VOE7UTzJLs=

my php look like this:

```
$pagex = $this->page;
$patternx = '/("video_title":")(.*?)(")/i';
if(preg_match($patternx,$pagex,$arx)){  
    $key = $arx[2];
}               


$page = $this->page;
$pattern = '/("video_url":")(.*?)(")/i';
if(preg_match($pattern,$page,$ar)){ 
$link = $ar[2];
}
```

and it does not work. It show nothing.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the basics. You're inflexible with quotes (`["']`), you don't account for whitespace (`\s*`), you don't account for the `encodeURIComponent`, etc.

Comment: Why are you doing this with regex? Why not hava the Javascript send the object using JSON, and use `json_decode()` in PHP?

Comment: because the js part is inside the html

Comment: You're bouncing around between " use and ' use with no consistency. How is this a string in any language?

Comment: its a javascript, check here part of it: http://pastebin.com/Qmbp5aiW

Comment: and that javascript is inside html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "'disablePauseroll'  : disablePauseroll,
            'video_url'         : encodeURIComponent('WQFuk9Py2VC3jsCrPDJ69xtsj33MiXAElBzQw3TSHqOOyDYL0vRJELrB1hTTW3NG0A54kE2FVueuHMkQd8JveYb92eV+dYH4IUrrvJdP5Of9HGi+5i6GT11nL0dAv/ecyP4sB0jM8rVZzyS8imLarvPUvPuFPvvB8nwYXZ2ZKon4IPjmtC8SPftaw0PSuZKMg735hLCraeAE3lMQbRwiY7yMHKmUHDALG1Ky+HBDiK20vAGEIMwzPwKZmhbBXRGiHzEiXiRk4JgaVyp6N66EALao7VOE7UTzJLs='),
            'encrypted'         : 'true',
            'video_title'       : \"some cool vids title here\",";

preg_match("/encodeURIComponent\('([^']+)/", $string, $match);

echo $match[1]; // URL

preg_match('/video_title[^"]+"([^"]+)/', $string, $match);

echo $match[1]; // Title
```

This will extract the text string between the `'` quotes within `encodeURIComponent()` and the 2nd will extract the text within the `"` quotes for `video_title`

Comment: thanks, this work fine. how about the video_title do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For video_title (allows escaped `"` in the title):

```
'video_title'\s*:\s*"(.*?)*(?<!\\)"
```

In PHP:

```
$pattern='\'video_title\'\s*:\s*"(.*?)*(?<!\\)"';
```

And for url:

```
'video_url'\s*:\s*encodeURIComponent\('([^']*)'\)
```

And:

```
$pattern='\'video_url\'\s*:\s*encodeURIComponent\(\'([^\']*)\'\)';
```

Comment: like this: $patternx = '/'video_title'\s*:\s*"(.*?)*(?<!\\)"\s*,/i'; 
is that correct?

Comment: preg_match("/'video_title'\s*:\s*"(.*?)*(?<!\\)"\s*, $pagex, $match);

this return me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('

Comment: You need to escape the `'`: `$patternx = '\'video_title\'\s*:\s*"(.*?)*(?<!\)"\s*,';` (And why `/i`?)